# javascript loading MVC 4 razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

It says the javascript cant be found. I tried using other code for script src but still it doesnt work.Whenever I try to run this it says "Failed to load resource 404 the blah/blah/*js can`t be found.

```
http://localhost:51835/Scripts/ui.jqgrid.css

I tried googling everything but it still can`t find the script

@using System.Web.Script.Services`enter code here`
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js")"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui.jqgrid.css")"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>viewTry</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
        url: '',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['Id','First Name', 'Last Name', 'Last 4 SSN', 'Department', 
                'Age', 'Salary',  "Address",'Marital Status'],
        colModel: [
        { name: '_id', index: '_id', width: 20, stype: 'text' },
        { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 150 },
        { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 150 },
           { name: 'LastSSN', index: 'LastSSN', width: 100 },
        { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Age', index: 'Salary', width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary', width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 150, sortable: false },
        { name: 'MaritalStatus', index: 'MaritalStatus', width: 100, sortable: false }
      ],
        rowNum: 10,
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "List Employee Details"
    });
</script> 

        <table id="JQGridDemo"></table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show my your full path of files?

Comment: I just suddenly realized what is my mistake. thanks for that.

Comment: can you provide the full path of jquery.jqGrid.js , ui.jqgrid.css , and this document's full path